# Export PyDev Pygame project as .exe?

Tags: python, pygame, pydev

I'm currently using PyDev to build my python game right now, and I just finished; but I still have one more thing to do: Export as an executable.

Right now, I have a folder called 'resources' that stores all my game music, sounds, and images. There is also 'Game.py' which is a game I created with pygame.

My question is: How would I export the whole workspace - 'resources' and 'Game.py' -  as a .exe? Py2exe and PyInstaller don't seem to be working.